# Can I capture the click of an <a> link

Tags: html, asp.net

Is it possible to capture the click of the HTML link tag `<a href...>`. I am using now LinkButton controls, but they don't do the work for me everywhere in the website, so somewhere will be nice if I could be able to run something in the code-behind upon a click of an `<a>` link.

I did `<a href="#" runat="server" id="vision">More info</a>` and tried to use it in the code-behind as `vision. ....` but it's not possible. :D

What I want is, when it's clicked - then catch that event and do smth else.

Comment: @tymeJV - I wrote that I am using LinkButton controls, but they're not useful for me everywhere in the website. That is why I need smth else.

Comment: You could apply a client side click event handler to make an AJAX request to a server side method to capture the click.

Comment: @Syspect -- My bad, read too fast.

Answer (score 1):

Well, you can have a hidden button as below.

aspx Markup...

```
<a href="javascript;" id="clickHere" >Click Here</a>
<asp:Button ID="btnHidden" OnClick="hdnButton_Click" runat="server" style="display:none;">
```

jQuery code...

```
$("#clickHere").click(function() {
    $("#<%= btnHidden.ClientID %>").click();
});
```

Server side code...

```
protected void btnHidden_Click(Object sender, Eventargs e)
{
    //do your stuff here...
}
```

Comment: this will not work in many scenario because the button id can change once its renders on the client side.

Comment: Thanks @Anand, I had used the ID for example purpose. I have edited the answer to get the `ClientID`.

Answer (score 0):

I think that "onclick" can fix your problem.

See this exemple:

```
<a href="#" onclick="doSomethingElseInJavaScript()">Click Here</a>
```

Or, if you prefer:

```
<a href="javascript:doSomethingElseInJavascript()">Click Here</a>
```

EDIT 1: Use doSomethingElseInJavascript with AJAX

```
function doSomethingElseInJavascript()
{
$.ajax({
        type: "post",
        url: "mypage.php?data="+data,

        success  : function(data){
             window.location.href="anotherpage.html";
        },
        error    : function(){
             alert("Fatal Error");
        }

         });

}
```

Comment: Question is about run something in code behind not on client side.

Comment: Use your imagination, the method "doSomethingElseInJavascript()" can have a Ajax method to call something else in server side.

Answer (score 0):

You can use jQuery libray ~ Ajax libray to contact server-side, using method **$_GET**, **$_POST** or whatever.

There are few ways to do that, one using jQuery event:

```
$('a').click(function (){
 //Use ajax libray here..
});
```

Event `on` in jQuery libray:

```
$('a').on("click", function (){
 //Ajax..
});
```

And HTML `onclick` event:

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function func(){
 // Ajax
});
</script>
<a href="#" onclick="func();">click to func(); function</a>
```